# expect not properly matching patterns

Tags: python, sudo, pexpect

I have been trying to match pattern when sudo password is inserted using sendline but it is somehow not working correctly. I maybe doing something wrong. I have tried various ways but nothing works....please help.

example:

```
import pexpect
USER = "someuser"
HOST = "IPADDRESSOFREMOTEHOST"
PORT="22"
PORTINFO = "-p " + PORT
CONNECTION = USER + "@" + HOST
SSHTIMEOUT = 5
CMDTIMEOUT=1
SSHOPTIONS = "-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oPubkeyAuthentication=no -oConnectTimeout={0}".format(SSHTIMEOUT)
CMD = 'ssh %s %s %s' % (SSHOPTIONS, CONNECTION, PORTINFO)
PWD = "correctpassword"

child = pexpect.spawn(CMD, timeout=int(CMDTIMEOUT), encoding='utf-8')
r1 = child.expect(['password: ', 'Connection timed out', 'No address associated with hostname','Could not resolve hostname'])
print(r1)
0 -> matching 'password'
child.sendline(PWD)
r2 = child.expect(['Permission denied', '[#\$]'])
print(r2)
1 -> matching '[#\$]'
child.sendline("df -h")
child.sendline("lscpu")
child.sendline("sudo ls /")
r3 = child.expect(['password','[sudo]','[#\$]'])
print(r3)
1 -> matching '[sudo]'
child.sendline(PWD)
r3 = child.expect(['password','[sudo]','[#\$]'])
print(r3)
1 -> AGAIN matching '[sudo]' where it should really be matching '[#\$]'] this is wrong
```

see the last line it **always matches '[sudo]'**, it should really be matching '[#\$]' as correct password was sent.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong, it seems that it is not matching against prompt line but instead it is matching against whole output? I am not too sure. If this is the case how can, I ever figure out if correct sudo password was entered or not?

-Jatin

Comment: Why put `sudo` in brackets? `[sudo]` is a pattern matching the single character `s` or `u` or `d` or `o`. Perhaps you meant just `'sudo'`.

Comment: when you send child.sendline("sudo ls /"), the prompts start with [sudo] so I put that, you see password is at very 1st but it doesn't match ever. I am not sure what is happening why isn't it matching password and it only matches [sudo] all the time...

Answer (score 0):

When using pexpect you should always do an `expect` after a `send`, in order to move the pexepct cursor forward. Otherwise, pexpect (which is not greedy) will stop at the first instance of your search string within the first 2000 characters, and it may end up several commands behind your current command.

For example, after the spawn:

```
child.sendline("df -h")  # Prints the directory listing and a prompt
child.sendline("lscpu")  # Prints the architecture information and a prompt
child.sendline("sudo ls /")  # Expects a password, then prints a directory listing
child.expect(["password", "[sudo]", "[#\$]"])  # Finds the password prompt, since it is listed first
child.sendline("correctpassword")
child.expect(["password", "[sudo]", "[#\$]"])  # Finds the earlier sudo prompt, since it was not consumed in the previous expect, and it is listed before the prompt!
```

I simplified and tested your code:

> **NOTE** - Tested on Linux 5.14.16 using Python 3.9. Remote machine is Ubuntu 8.04.

```
import sys
import pexpect

try:
    child = pexpect.spawn(
        'ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ' +
        '-oPubkeyAuthentication=no -oConnectTimeout=5 someuser@192.168.x.x')
    child.logfile = sys.stdout.buffer
    index = child.expect_exact(['password:',
                                'Network is unreachable',
                                'Connection timed out',
                                'No address associated with hostname',
                                'Could not resolve hostname', ])
    if index == 0:
        child.sendline('correctpassword')
        # Use expect_exact to avoid misinterpreting characters as regex delimiters
        child.expect_exact('$')
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Unable to SSH: Found index {0}'.format(index))
    child.sendline('df -h')
    child.expect_exact('$')
    child.sendline('lshw')  # my remote machine does not use lscpu
    child.expect_exact('$')
    child.sendline('sudo ls /')
    index = child.expect_exact(['password', '$', ])
    if index == 0:
        child.sendline('correctpassword')
        # Use expect_exact to avoid misinterpreting characters as regex delimiters
        child.expect_exact('$')

    # ... add additional code here ...

    child.sendline('exit')
    child.expect_exact(['closed', '$', ])
    child.close()
except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
    print('Error: Unable to find the expect search string.\n' +
          pexpect.ExceptionPexpect(pexpect.TIMEOUT).get_trace())
except pexpect.EOF:
    print('Error: Child closed unexpectedly.\n' +
          pexpect.ExceptionPexpect(pexpect.EOF).get_trace())
```

**Output:**

```
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.x.x' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
someuser@192.168.x.x's password: correctpassword

Linux ********** Thu Apr 10 13:58:00 UTC 2008 i686

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

To access official Ubuntu documentation, please visit:
http://help.ubuntu.com/
You have mail.
Last login: Tue Dec 14 20:17:52 2021 from 192.168.x.x
someuser@192.168.x.x:~$ df -h
df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda1             228M   25M  192M  12% /boot
someuser@192.168.x.x:~$ lshw
lshw
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
...
configuration: driver=ahci latency=64 module=ahci
someuser@192.168.x.x:~$ sudo ls /
sudo ls /
bin    dev    ...
cdrom  home   lib    mnt    proc   srv    usr
someuser@192.168.x.x:~$ exit
exit
logout
Connection to 192.168.x.x closed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```